# Why can't I read the property color?

Tags: javascript, html, object, canvas

I wrote a little program, which in I'm trying to do a moving "bubbly" background. For this I'm using HTML canvas. I tried to represent each bubble with an JavaScript object. When I loop through the list, I'm getting an error. The error is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'color' of undefined
    at drowBouble (app.js:44)
    at drowBoubles (app.js:38)
    at generateBoubles (app.js:29)
    at app.js:57
drowBouble @ app.js:44
drowBoubles @ app.js:38
generateBoubles @ app.js:29
(anonymous) @ app.js:57
```

I tried to console.log() the index in the function drowBouble(), and in the last iteration the result was undefined. Why? How can I fix it?

My app.js:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("cv");
let width = window.innerWidth * 0.98;
let height = window.innerHeight * 0.97;
canvas.width = width;
canvas.height = height;

var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var boubles = [];

var createBouble = function() {
  let x = Math.floor( width * Math.random());
  let y = Math.floor(height * Math.random());
  let color = getColor();
  let radius = 30 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
  let xAcc = 10;
  let yAcc = 10;
  return {x, y, color, radius, xAcc, yAcc};
}

var getColor = function() {
  return 'rgba(' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ', ' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ', ' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + ', ' + 0.3 + ')';
}

var generateBoubles = function(amount) {
  for (let i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    boubles.push(createBouble());
  }
  drowBoubles();
}

var drowBoubles = function() {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  for (let i = 0; i < boubles.length; i++) {
    drowBouble(i);
    updateBouble(i);
  }
  setTimeout(drowBouble(), 100);
}

var drowBouble = function(index) {
  console.log(index);
  console.log(boubles.length);
  context.fillStyle = boubles[index].color;
  context.beginPath();
  context.arc(boubles[index].x, boubles[index].y, boubles[index].radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  context.fill();
}

var updateBouble = function(index){
    let bouble = boubles[index];
    bouble.x += bouble.xAcc;
    bouble.y += bouble.yAcc;
    boubles[index] = bouble;
}

generateBoubles(20);
```

Comment: ```setTimeout(drowBouble(), 100);``` You're neglecting to pass in an index here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that instead of drowBoubles() i called drowBouble()...

Comment: You don't have to invoke function in setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

Error is in the setTimeout function, you are calling the drowBubble function (invoked) without parameters.

Try to change from

`setTimeout(drowBouble(), 100)`

To

`setTimeout(drowBoubles, 100)`

Comment: Thank you! I changed it it ti   requestAnimationFrame(drowBoubles);

Answer (score -1):

From what I can see you are trying to read something that Is not readable. You want to see the color? Then give it a name. what’s happening now is that you are telling the client to read the color was generated from the method but it’s not held in any attribute. Try and give it a name like a const colorName and then use it in the console log.